# huawei map map.animateCamera not working?

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, huawei-map-kit

i have now both GMS and HMS in the same app.
Both in different classes.

but when i just this code:

```
   val cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(builder.build(), 50)
        map.animateCamera(cu, object : CancelableCallback {
            override fun onCancel() {}
            override fun onFinish() {
                val zout = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomBy(-2.0f)
                map.animateCamera(zout)
            }
        })
```

It works smoothly on Google, but it doesnt work smooth on Huawei devices.
The map does not move at all on the huawei class i have made.

but on the other hand when i try to use:

```
 map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(builder.build().center, 18.0.toFloat()))
```

Its somehow working. But i dont want to move, i want to animate. So why is the animation not working for HMS??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

figured it out. just had to update the map-kit gradle version to the newest version. now it works